# Identity of pre 1930s US battleship

Tags: military, identification, ships

[image: Unidentified US battleship]

Need help in identifying this battleship--USS Nevada, Pennsylvannia or Arizona?

Comment: The ships you named all have 1 stack; this one has 2 stacks.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battleships_of_the_United_States_Navy#Dreadnought_battleships for ships with two stacks BETWEEN the wire masts.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the [Utah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USSutah2.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to History Beta!

The battleship in question is a [Florida-class battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida-class_battleship) (look for [images](https://www.google.com/search?q=uss+florida&tbm=isch) of the USS Florida before its 1924 modernization).
[image]

The picture clearly shows the 10 × 12 in (305 mm)/45 caliber Mark 5 guns and the 16 × 5 in (127 mm)/51 cal guns.